# MySQL: why is a index column marked as "BTREE?"

Tags: mysql

lets see two tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE  `orders_products` (
  `ORDER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `QUANTITY` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`,`PRODUCT_ID`,`USER_ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_orders_products_3` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `FK_orders_products_2` (`PRODUCT_ID`) **USING BTREE**,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES `orders` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_ID`) REFERENCES `products` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_3` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

another:

```
CREATE TABLE  `products_pictures_comments` (
  `PICTURE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `COMMENT` text NOT NULL,
  `DATEAT` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PICTURE_ID`,`USER_ID`,`DATEAT`),
  KEY `FK_products_pictures_comments_2` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_pictures_comments_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PICTURE_ID`) REFERENCES `products_pictures` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_pictures_comments_2` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

as you can see, a USING BTREE appears from an unknown reason. I checked the tables with `show index from` command, and all of them said BTREE for Index_type. But it only appears in FK_orders_products_2 foreign key. Why?

EDIT: these table definitions were generated by SHOW CREATE TABLE!

Comment: also appears on the primary key line as well...

Comment: yes, this is also strange :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd like to mention that BTREE is a default index type for most of the storage engines in MYSQL. I can see that you are using InnoDB storage engine with both statements and BTREE is the default type for the indexing in the innodb storage engine though you don't specify the keyword.

I am pretty sure that you might have kept "USING BTREE" keyword while creating the table orders_products table which results "USING BTREE" included with DDL script which was produced by SHOW CREATE TABLE.

--------------Experiment--------------

DROP TABLE zzz_test1;

DROP TABLE zzz_test2;

CREATE TABLE zzz_test1(id INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(id) USING BTREE);

CREATE TABLE zzz_test2(id INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(id));

SHOW CREATE TABLE zzz_test1;

---

------------OUTPUT--------------

CREATE TABLE `zzz_test1` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

---

SHOW CREATE TABLE zzz_test2;

------------OUTPUT--------------

CREATE TABLE `zzz_test2` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1):

Because a btree (assuming it means balanced rather than just binary) is an efficient data structure for maintaining indexes.

It has reasonable insertion and deletion characteristics and *very* good search characteristics.

If your question is more along the lines of why it isn't used everywhere, that's almost certainly because it uses *other* methods.

Comment: thats OK, still I dont understand why that appears here, and wont appears another places.

Comment: Maybe because the other 'places' aren't indexed?

Comment: USER_ID isnt indexed neither

Answer (score 1):

well, that is normal, indexes are stored in Hash and btrees. BTREE is the data structure used for implementing index in older MySQL I think. But InnoDB engine has a new adaptive hashing technology which uses Hash table for indexing making it much more faster. There is nothing wrong there.

Comment: thats OK, still I dont understand why that appears here, and wont appears another places.

Comment: This is incorrect. The InnoDB engine only supports BTREE indexes. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-options